# Declare variable name dynamically

Tags: variables, dynamic, declaration, abap

The task is to create variable with dynamic *name*. Not type, but name! 
All the ways proposed to me (e.g. via `cl_abap_typedescr` and `cl_abap_elemdescr` classes) were useless.
I want to implement semantically something like this, but this syntax is incorrect:

```
CREATE DATA (name) TYPE var_type.
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Do you really want to create an entirely new variable?  (Almost certain you can't, and wondering why you would want to).  Or are you trying to reference one of many variables that is already declared dynamically?  For instance if you were trying to reference INGRP10, but have INGRP01 to INGRP40 declared, you could assign the variable dynamically to a field-symbol.

Comment: Referencing already declared variable is easy and well-documented but it's not the point.

Comment: I want to declare and create dynamically and I want to do this because of the user requirements. You are concluding that it is impossible?

Comment: You might need to approach this from a different angle. You could define an itab/structure dynamically (example here http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Dynamic+Internal+table) and you can then specify the field names within that structure at runtime.

Comment: Now I'm using this way with CREATE_DYNAMIC_TABLE. I store my structure as a field of itab. But the problem bothers me fundamentally. In order for further avoiding asking silly questions))

Comment: It is not possible/feasible because the language has so little support for dynamic variable names. Which is a good thing, imagine debugging this stuff..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if 'name' was declared as a field-symbol it would work.

Effect
This statement declares a symbolic field called . At runtime, you can assign a concrete field to the field symbol using ASSIGN. All operations performed with the field symbol then directly affect the field assigned to it.

Try this one out:

```
data:
  b_1 type i,
  b_2 type i,
  b_3 type i,
  b_4 type i,
  num1(1) type n,
  fldname type fieldname.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:
  <fld> type i.

do 4 times.
  num1 = sy-index.
  CONCATENATE 'B_' num1 into fldname.
  ASSIGN (fldname) to <fld>.
  <fld> = sy-index.
enddo.

write: b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4.
```

Comment: Good. For now this is most close variant.

Answer (score 0):

You basically cannot do this using any kind of ABAP syntax. You can of course write a function that mimics this using an internal table, something like this (I left out error handling)

```
class cl_dyn_variable definition.
  public section.

    methods create_variable
      importing i_name type clike
                i_type type string.

    methods get_variable
      importing i_name type clike
      returning value(r_data) type ref to data.

  private section.
    types: begin of lty_s_variable,  
             name type string,
             r_data type ref to data,
           end of lty_s_variable,
           lty_t_variable type sorted table of lty_s_variable with unique key name.

    data mt_variable type lty_t_variable.

endclass.

class cl_dyn_varaible implementation.

  method create_varaible.
    data ls_new_var type lty_s_variable.

    ls_new_var-name = i_name.
    create data ls_new_var-r_data type (i_type).
    insert ls_new_var into table mt_variable.

  endmethod.

  method get_variable.
    data lsr_var type ref to lty_s_variable.

    read table mt_variable with table key name = i_name
         reference into lsr_var.
    if sy-subrc <> 0.
      "...error handling 
    else.
      r_data = lsr_var->r_data.
    endif.
  endmethod.

endclass.
```