# How to create the name of Internal Table dynamically

Tags: abap

I want to create dynamically the ITAB's name e.g. itab_name = |it_itab{ time }|. where time is 1 or 2 or .... The itab will be type standard table of BAPIACGL09.
What I want to do is to run the BAPI 'BAPI_ACC_BILLING_POST' more than once and I want to fill the structures and tables more than once, namely I want to have GIT_ACCOUNTGL, GIT_ACCOUNTGL01, GIT_ACCOUNTGL02 etc and run the BAPI as many times as the times of the ITABs & Structures I have.
Can someone tell me how to do?
Thanks

Comment: What is the next step? Where will you use them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare variable name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454561/declare-variable-name-dynamically)

Comment: It isn't possible by standard means, I asked this 7 years ago

Comment: The title "How to create the name of Internal Table dynamically" doesn't reflect correctly the question, I understand it more like the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454561/declare-variable-name-dynamically) asked by Suncatcher. What you want is to store all the results of a BAPI called several times, and how to use them later.

Comment: No Sandra. My question is how to name dynamically an ITAB as we can do with the fields. Now I want to use it with BAPI but later maybe I want to do it with sth else.

Answer (score 4):

Use a table of tables. Each line represents one of the itabs you describe. Address the tables by their index, not by some name.

```
TYPES table_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiacgl09 WITH EMPTY KEY.
TYPES collection_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF table_type WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA all_results TYPE collection_type.

" collect the results
DO 100 TIMES.
  DATA(single_result) = " call bapi
  INSERT single_result INTO TABLE all_results.
ENDDO.

" access a specific result by index
DATA(forty_second_result) = all_results[ 42 ].

" iterate all results
LOOP AT all_results INTO single_result.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I do not know this, as I have never use it. Is it possible to have an example? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Florian. Because BAPIs need more tables, structures and variables, can we change the 1st line as follow (I am writing in 1 line as I cannot break it):              Types: Begin of table_type,                                                                      accountgl type standard table of BAPIACGL01,                             
ACCOUNTTAX  type standard table of  BAPIACTX01,                                          DOCUMENTHEADER type BAPIACHE01,                                                             OBJ_KEY like BAPIACHE01-OBJ_KEY,              End of table_type.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you call "dynamic", but one possibility based on the proposal of Florian (using a table, a "table of complex structure" in my case) is this one:

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF ty_bapiarglist,
          " arguments passed to the BAPI
          accountgl TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiacgl01 WITH EMPTY KEY,
          " ...
          " arguments returned by the BAPI
          return    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiret2 WITH EMPTY KEY,
          " ...
        END OF ty_bapiarglist.

DATA: bapiarglist  TYPE ty_bapiarglist,
      bapiarglists TYPE TABLE OF ty_bapiarglist.

"++++++++++++++
" Call BAPI
" Fill lists of arguments
"++++++++++++++

LOOP AT someitab...

  " fill arguments to transmit
  " bapiarglist-accountgl = ...

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ACC_BILLING_POST'
     ...
     TABLES
       accountgl = bapiarglist-accountgl
       return    = bapiarglist-return
       ...

  APPEND bapiarglist TO bapiarglists.

ENDLOOP.

"++++++++++++++
" Later usage
"++++++++++++++

LOOP AT bapiarglists INTO bapiarglist.
  ...
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks Sandra. I will check it and I will let you know.